# Trigonometry on circle as function of distances to (-r,0 ) and (r,0)

Tags: trigonometry

I have two point A and B on a circle centered at the origin $ O = (0,0)$ with radius r

And I am only told:

- A and B are both on the upper half plane ($ y \ge 0 $ )
- the distance $a_1$ from A to the point $(r,0)$
- the distance $a_2$ from A to the point $(-r,0)$
- the distance $b_1$ from B to the point $(r,0)$
- the distance $b_2$ from B to the point $(-r,0)$

(PS $r$ itself is **not** given)

How can I calculate the $\angle AOB$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is the picture you should have in mind, where $AE = a1,AD=a2,BE=b1,BD=b2$.
The answer to your question is $\lvert {\alpha - \beta}\lvert$.
To find $\alpha$ you can write law of cosines in the $\bigtriangleup{AOE}$ and $\bigtriangleup{AOD}$. Respectively
$$a1^2 = 2r^2-2r^2\cos{\alpha}$$
$$a2^2 = 2r^2+2r^2\cos{\alpha}$$
From these two equations it's easy to find $\alpha = \arccos{\frac{a_{1}^2-a_{2}^2}{a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2}}$ 
The process of finding $\beta$ is identical and $\beta = \arccos{\frac{b_{1}^2-b_{2}^2}{b_{1}^2+b_{2}^2}}$

So answer to your question is $\lvert \arccos{\frac{a_{1}^2-a_{2}^2}{a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2}} - \arccos{\frac{b_{1}^2-b_{2}^2}{b_{1}^2+b_{2}^2}} \lvert$

Comment: That is exactly the picture I had in mind! Just replace **E** by **C**. Can you tell me where you drew this and how you can include pictures in answers? I'm new here, a link to a tutorial would be great

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

let $M=(r,0)$ and $N=(-r,0)$.

The triangles $AMN$ and $BMN$ are rectangles and :

1) the height $AH$ with respect to the hypotenuse $MN$ is $AH=r \sin(\angle AOM)$

2) the height $BK$ with respect to the hypotenuse $MN$ is $BK= r\sin(\angle BOM)$

3) $\overline{AN}\times \overline{AM}=2r\overline{AH}$ and $\overline{BN}\times \overline{BM}=2r\overline{BK}$

4) $\angle BOA = \angle BOM - \angle AOM$

Answer (score 0):

For sake of convenience let **A** be closer to **C(-r,0)** and **B** closer to **D(r,0)**. **O** is the origin. We know  $\mathbf{\angle AOC, \angle BOD}$ from cosine rule (sides **OC = OA = OB = OD = r** and $\mathbf{AC = a_2}$ and $\mathbf{BD = b_1}$). Now $\mathbf{\angle AOC + \angle AOB + \angle BOD = 180^0}$, so $\mathbf{\angle AOB = 180^0 - (\angle AOC + \angle BOD)}$